# Styling progress bar with inline style

Tags: html, css, progress-bar

I am trying to set the progress bar color into red using inline style. I need to do it in this way because I only have access to the `<body>` part of the document. This is the style that I need to apply:

```
progress { color: red }
progress::-moz-progress-bar { background: red;}
progress::-webkit-progress-value { background: red; }
progress[aria-valuenow]:before  { background: red; }
```

I tried with only `<progress style="background: red;">` but I get an incorrect effect, the progress bar color turns into blue with red background. Could you guide my to right direction to get desired style? thank you in advance.

Here a live example: https://jsfiddle.net/z36d3f6L/

Comment: You're trying to style a pseudo-element/shadow-dom with inline styling, that's not possible.

Comment: is it possible with javascript? The problem is that I am completely hands tied because I can not touch head section of the html file

Comment: You should go for a custom HTML/CSS solution.

Comment: Just so you know, you can absolutely add a stylesheet from inside a `body` tag. Doesn't need to be in the `head`.

Comment: @Brachamul, that is new to me! Thank you.